# Select-Option num value vs SQL num_row

Tags: php, mysql, html, while-loop, mysql-num-rows

I have a big dilemma, I'm generating data from MySQL into a form so, the problem is that while the first row generated by SQL is 0 the select option in the form is interpreting the first value as 1.
Would not be any problem if I wouldn't wanted to throw out some data from within this Query. But here is the code:

```
<select id="exp_address" name="exp_address" onChange="document.getElementById('exp_city').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-exp_city'); document.getElementById('exp_dist').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-exp_distr'); document.getElementById('exp_address_val').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-exp_city_val')">
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < $expselnum; $i++){
    $exps_add_id = mysql_result($expsel,$i,'address_id');
    $exps_address = mysql_result($expsel,$i, "address");
    $exps_city = mysql_result($expsel,$i, "city");
    $exps_distr_val = mysql_result($expsel,$i, "district");
    echo "<option value=$exps_add_id data-num=$i data-exp_city = '$exps_city' data-exp_distr = '$exps_distr_val' data_exp_city_val = '$exps_city'>$exps_address</option>";      
}
?>
</select>
```

and here is the HTML code generated:

```
<select onChange="Here is some JS to change the value of District and City inputs">
<option value=1 data-num=0 data-exp_city = 'BUCURESTI' data-exp_distr = 'Bucuresti' data_exp_city_val = 'BUCURESTI' [selected by default]>Another Address in RO</option><option value=2 data-num=1 data-exp_city = 'OTOPENI-IF' data-exp_distr = 'Ilfov' data_exp_city_val = 'OTOPENI-IF'>Some address in RO</option></select>
<input name="exp_city" type="text" id="exp_city" style="text-align:left;" value="OTOPENI-IF" size="30" readonly="readonly">
```

If you compare the value and data-num att in the option tag, you'll see that they are different by an unit, WHY. The first value of option is selected on page landing, but the city input shows the next value from the query.
How can I work this around? 
Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: your method of getting data from mysql is ancient and ugly. Get your data into array first and then use it to produce HTML. I am sure it will solve every your present problem as a side effect

Comment: Thank you @ColShrapnel, I shall put my hands on a PHP&MySQL book to find out how to get the Array alterntive, unfortunately I'm just a Graph. Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not stated very subtle, I agree with Shrapnel's comment. However, this might fix your 'problem' (I don't really understand the question, though):

```
for($i = 0; $i < $expselnum; $i++){
```

change to:

```
for($i = 1; $i < $expselnum; $i++){
```

Comment: Thanks @rijk, this change will hide the first record of the table.